# How to show values from textbox while clicking on textnox field in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a textbox with autocomplete,  now I am trying **When user click on textbox all the values should come in drop-down**  and also autocomplete will work as it is working.

autocomplete is working fine but When user click on ***Headline Textbox*** all the values should be shown in drop-down without any typing!
[image]
**component.html**

```
<div class="form-field col-lg-12">
<label class="label" for="name">Date</label>
<input class="input-text js-input" [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" name="date" type="date"
                max="{{yesterday | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" required>
        </div>
<div class="form-field col-lg-12 ">
<label class="label" for="company">Publication</label>

<input [(ngModel)]="pubTitleKeyUp" (ngModelChange)="keyUpPublication(pubTitleKeyUp)" name="pub"
                class="input-text js-input" type="text" required autocomplete="off">


<div class="search-result" *ngIf="publications" style="max-height: 120px;">
<ul style="margin:0; padding:5px;">
<li *ngFor="let pub of publications">
<a (click)="onClickPublication(pub)"> {{ pub.Title }} -{{ pub.city }} </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
<div class="form-field col-lg-12">
<label class="label" for="message">Headline</label>
<div class="spinner-border" role="status">
<span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
            </div>
            <input [(ngModel)]="articleTitleKeyUp" (ngModelChange)="keyUpArticle(articleTitleKeyUp)" name="article" class="input-text js-input" type="text" required autocomplete="off">


<div class="search-result" *ngIf="articles" style="max-height: 100px;">
<ul style="margin:0; padding:5px; max-height: 100px;">
<li *ngFor="let article of articles">
                        <a (click)="onClickArticle(article)">{{article.Title}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
onFocusPublication() {
    console.log(this.selectedDate);
  }

  /* POST article with PUB id and Date */

  keyUpPublication(e) {
    let k = e as string
    let kl = k.length

    this.publications = this.allPubs.filter(p => {
      // let title = p.Title.toLowerCase()
      // return title.substring(0, kl) == k.toLowerCase()

    let title = p.Title + ' -' + p.city;
    return title.toLowerCase().includes(k.toLowerCase());
    })
  }

  onClickPublication(pub: IPub) {
    this.pubTitleKeyUp = pub.Title + ' -' + pub.city;
    this.selectedPub = pub
    this.publications = []
  }


  /* POST article with PUB id and Date */

  keyUpArticle(e) {
    if (!this.selectedPub) {
      return alert('Please select a Date and publication first!');
    }

    let k = e as string
    let kl = k.length

    if (this.allArticles?.length) {
      return this.articles = this.allArticles.filter(p => {
        let title = p.Title.toLowerCase()
        return title.substring(0, kl) == k.toLowerCase()
      })
    }

    this.isLoading = true

    this.article
      .postArticlesData({
        pubid: this.selectedPub.PubId,
        pubdate: this.selectedDate,
      })
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.isLoading = false
        this.allArticles = data.result || [];

        this.articles = this.allArticles.filter(p => {
          let title = p.Title.toLowerCase()
          return title.substring(0, kl) == k.toLowerCase()
        })
      }, (e) => {
        this.isLoading = false
      });
  }

  /* When article gets clicked */
  onClickArticle(article) {
    // console.log(article);
    this.articleTitleKeyUp = article.Title;
    this.selectedArticle = article;
    this.articles = [];
  }

  /* ON pub change */
  onPubChange() {
    console.log(this.selectedDate, this.selectedPub);
  }

  /* ON submit form */
  onSubmit() {
    if (this.selectedArticle && this.selectedDate && this.selectedPub) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('delete-article/' + this.selectedArticle.ArticleID)
    } else {
      alert('Please select Caldendar, and then Publication');
    }
  }
```

Comment: is it articles loaded before render the View?

Comment: when I click on textbox and start typing API will call and after typing data shown according to autocomplete values @VENKATESHCHAVVAKULA

Comment: if we want to show all the values when dropdown opens you have to load articles ,
try lo load some random articles first then it will automatically view when dropdown opens, then can get articles by user key evnets

Comment: @VENKATESHCHAVVAKULA I am aware about this but I am clueless about code, I mean I thought i need to make small changes and it is done.

Comment: is it postArticlesData  function (api) will give  all the results without send user key?

Comment: postArticleData takes two values from user i.e. date and pubid which is required by api to show values in textbox

Comment: when you are select pubid and date is there any event or function is called ?

Comment: yes When I select date the date value is stored and same with pubid and then both used in `postArticlesData` for calling the api and getting data

Comment: can u update the Html With that date and pubid input in question  then will give you the code snippet

Comment: can u try with udated answer

Comment: hi i think you git it bit wrong, When user select date a date value is stored and then when user click on publication - pubid is stored, now when user click on headline textbox api is fire with payload - date and pubid and data will shown

Answer (score 1):

```
1.can u load articles here
```

```
    onClickPublication(pub: IPub) {
        this.pubTitleKeyUp = pub.Title + ' -' + pub.city;
        this.selectedPub = pub
        this.publications = []
         if(this.selectedDate && !this.article.length) this.loadArticles()
    
      }
    
    loadArticles(){
    this.article
          .postArticlesData({
            pubid: this.selectedPub.PubId,
            pubdate: this.selectedDate,
          })
          .subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.articles = data.result || [];
          }, (e) => {
             // error
          });
        }
```

2.In html date in date input all event

```
    (ngModelChange)="changeDate(selectedDate)"
    
    in ts
    changeDate(data){
    if(data && this.selectedPub && !this.articles.lenght){
    this.loadArticles()
    }
```

Comment: getting error `if(this.selectedDate && !this.article.length) this.loadArticles()` cannot find loadArticles() and `length` does not exist

Comment: you will have to add     loadArticles() mention above

Comment: I did add but still is say  for loadArticles() and this.article.length

Comment: @archana am not getting you